# Why isn't this local variable initialized in Java?

Tags: java

I am learning Java and I know that I must initialize a local variable when I use it. However, I just found a code from the book and the code is: 
I wonder why in this case the variable volume is not initialized?

```
public static double cubeVolume(double sideLength)
{
    double volume;
    if (sideLength>=0)
    {
        volume=sideLength*sideLength*sideLength;
    }
    else
   {
      volume=0;
   }
   return volume;
}
```

Comment: return sideLength>=0?(sideLength*sideLength*sideLength):0;
Would be more cool way to handle this case :P

Comment: The variable `volume` will always be assigned a value either in `if` or `else`. Ergo no explicit initialization required.

Comment: Read up on the difference between declaration, initialization, and initialization at declaration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule is that it must be initialised **before it is used**, since on both branches of the if statement `volume` has been initialised  before it is returned (aka used) the compiler can guarantee that it will have been initialised before being used.

If you attempted to use `volume` before the if statement you will again receive that compilation error. Equally if it wasn't initialised on all branches (in this case both sides of the if statement) you would get the error.

## Examples

The following examples may give some incite into when this is likely to be a problem:

ok (but pointless):

```
double volume; //<--declared
volume=6;  //<--initialised
double volumeUsed=2*volume;
```

ok:

```
boolean useUpper=true; //<-- useUpper declared and initialised
double volume;
if (useUpper){
    volume=6; //<--initialised
}else{
    volume=7; //<--initialised
}
double volumeUsed=2*volume;
```

not ok (volume not known when used):

```
double volume;
double volumeUsed=2*volume;
```

not ok (volume **may** not be known when used - if useUpper were false):

```
boolean useUpper=true;
double volume;
if (useUpper){
    volume=6; //<--initialised
}
//volume may not be initialised
double volumeUsed=2*volume;
```

not ok: used before being initialised

```
double volume;
double volumeUsed=2*volume;
if (sideLength>=0)
{
    volume=sideLength*sideLength*sideLength; //<--initialised (too late)
}
else
{
   volume=0;
}
return volume;
```

Comment: so why not initialize it at `double volume;`?

Comment: oh, in particular you can force a compile error if you mess up the second else block. I'd +1 this if you add that.

Comment: @djechlin does example 4 cover that?

Comment: What about declaring a variable without initializing before the for loop and use the loop to count the value of the variable and then try to print out the value of the variable outside of the for loop. I know this is a compiler error but I want to know why this is a compiler error.Thanks.

Comment: @user3504084 would that be using `variable++`? That is equivalent to `variable=variable+1`, this again is using `variable` before it is initialised (aka set as having a value)

Comment: I got it. Now I am clear about initializing variables. Thank you for your excellent explaination!

Comment: @user3504084 Great, glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

Because the writer doesn't have any value for `volume` until the `if` is evaluated.

Other options include:

```
double volume = 16.0; // Random. Wrong. Bug-prone.
```

or:

```
double volume = 0.0; // Conveys that 0 is somehow a valid value. 
// or that another value might not be entered.
```

Of course in this case `0.0` is indeed a perfectly valid value, so this option is all right:

```
double volume = 0.0;
if(sideLength >= 0) {
    volume = sideLength * sideLength * sideLength;
}
```

But this arguably raises the question, why did we set `volume` twice? I think not a big deal, but some coders may not prefer it. Now this is getting advanced, but if `volume` needed to take the `final` modifier, e.g. because it appears in a closure later, this would be illegal:

```
final double volume = 0.0;
if(sideLength >= 0) {
    volume = sideLength * sideLength * sideLength;  // compiler error
}
```

If the author prefers terseness (which I do not recommend here), this can all be done in one line as follows:

```
double volume = sideLength >=0 ? sideLength * sideLength * sideLength : 0;
```

And just one more example to be clever (this is terrible, don't do this):

```
double volume = Math.max(sideLength * sideLength * sideLength, 0);
// does not generalize to even dimensions
```

Answer (score -2):

Just do this instead:

```
public static double cubeVolume(double sideLength)
{
    double volume = 0;
    if (sideLength>=0)
    {
        volume=sideLength*sideLength*sideLength;
    }
   return volume;
}
```

Comment: The question is not about correcting the code. The question is why a sample code present in a book is not initializing a local variable.

Comment: "Because the writer doesn't have any value for `volume` until the `if` is evaluated."

Comment: From the answer below me, pretty much sums up why